# Firefox Inspector output doesn't match rendered page

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, svg

#### Question

I have a situation where the Firefox page render does not match the inspector html- that is, if I copy the inspector's `outerHTML` into a new document, it renders correctly. *How is this possible?*

Is this definitely a Firefox bug, or is there some intermediate render state where the inspector output has been updated but the page view hasn't? (If so, how would I force the render to progress past this intermediate state?)

#### Extra Details

- I can also "fix" the render by manually (in the inspector) editing the attributes that aren't displaying correctly.

  - Specifically, for example, I might have a case where the code is calling `setAttribute('width',10)`, which causes the inspector to say `width="10"` but causes the page to display whatever the width was previously set to. If I manually replace the `width="10"` with `width="10"`, nothing happens; however, if I change `width="10"` to `width="11"`, the width displays as 11, after which I can set the width to 10 again to make it display correctly.
- Unfortunately, I have not yet been able to devise a simple example demonstrating this. My specific case is entangled with a fair amount of rendering code and involves changing dimensions on svg `foreignObject`s, but I'm mainly interested in the answer to the general question of how the inspector and page render can ever be out of sync.

  - (I have not been able to reproduce the issue in any other browsers, because Firefox is currently the only one that actually handles `foreignObject` correctly.)
- Firefox Version: 51.0.1 (64-bit) on Mac 10.10.5

#### Updates

- The main question still stands, but I'm increasingly thinking that a subtle Firefox bug is at the root of this. Some reasons:

  - Refreshing the page sometimes changes the behavior and sometimes doesn't.
  - I have tried adding `getBBox` calls right after each `setAttribute`, to force the browser to recalculate layout. This seems to work for every `foreignObject`- except for the first on the page. (However, sometimes the first one shows up- seemingly without anything being changed.)
  - JQuery's `.attr` seems to produce different behavior than `.setAttribute` and `.setAttributeNS`

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the error on 51.0.1 32-bit win 7.
In mdn in the examples they do use the width="100px" and not only width="100" but for the svg element and not the foreignObject.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

Though using either of both, I wasnt able to reproduce the out of sync you are commenting.
fobj = document.getElementById('f_object');
  fobj.setAttribute('width', 190);
  fobj.setAttribute('width', '190px');  Both worked as expected. 
Could it be an issue with the styles of the elements which are inside the foreignobject?

Comment: Thanks for trying that out. I have not been able to reproduce the behavior outside the full system either. I diff'd the foreignObject innerHTML before/after changing the dimensions, and nothing changes (including the inline styles). The computed style for the innermost content span reports 0x0 dimensions (despite having content) and doesn't correct itself until the foreignObject is manually updated.

Comment: Do you suspect a FF bug, or do you know of some intermediate render state?

Comment: I tried to render inside the foreignObject a big table/nested tables layout  of an email piece (XHTML compatible) and the result  was ok. Playing with  attributs through javascript the result where as expected. So maybe it's an issue with the amount of foreignObjects? I wouldn't discharge a bug either, being the element of new implementation.

Comment: I've had used more foreignObjects on the same page before, but thanks for the suggestion. The part that really baffles me is that the inspector displays exactly what it should but FF doesn't display it correctly.

Comment: I have a similar problem, also with an svg rendered dynamically after being loaded via a XMLHttpRequest (a template is loaded and modified on the fly, modifications appears only in the inspector but are not rendered)

Comment: @yota, unfortunately, I never got to the bottom of this- wish I could help.